# Add element to feedback form

Tags: html, css

I need to convert to HTML the design, among other things I need to make feedback form which has this element
[image]
What tags do I need to use for the layout of this element?

Comment: If you have never done HTML before you find a helpful introduction to the basics at http://www.w3schools.com/html/ . If you have already tried it, let us see what you have got.

Comment: I know how to work with HTML ans CSS, I ask about THIS element.

Comment: And what is THIS element? Is it the picture, the 'add photo' link or both?

Answer (score 1):

Each one is `<input type=file>`.  You'll want a class to capture them all together say...`class="photo"`.

You'll probably wrap it all in a `<div>` and it should definitely use some Javascript to replace those '+' images with the actual photo using AJAX (would go to server, get condensed/scaled as needed and sent back to browser).

```
<div class="photos">
  <form name="myform" action="usefulPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" />
    ...more
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

And there's a ton more stuff to do (CSS, JS, more HTML, etc).  This should just get you barely started.

PS - use the pic[] in "name" so more than one of them turns into an array and they name themselves automatically by number.